# PHP - How to remove newline with '>' before line break

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have my input text like this

```
bla;bla<ul>
<li>line one</li>
<li>line one</li>
<ul>bla
line two
line tree
```

I only want to replace the lines that contain '>' with blank space; 
other line that there is no '>' at the end of line will be ignore.

Output should be:

```
bla;bla<ul><li>line one</li><li>line one</li><ul>bla
line two
line tree
```

What the PHP code to replace the line should be?

I have tried

```
$output = preg_replace( "/\r|\n/", "", $text );
```

but it's not a good idea as that code will be applied to all line of $text

Thank you so much.

**Now I can solve the problem with this**

```
$output = preg_replace("/(?<=>)\s+(?=)/", "", $text );
```

Thank you so much

Comment: Please edit your question and add the code that you have tried that is not working for you.

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Comment: I edited a csv file that contain some html elements and cause error, so I want to remove all line break after '>' in html tags to keep them in single line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `>(?:\n|\r\n)` regex and replace it with `>` which will match a `>` only located at the end of line.

```
$text = "bla;bla<ul>\n<li>line one</li>\n<li>line one</li>\n<ul>bla\nline two\nline tree";
$output = preg_replace( "/>(?:\n|\r\n)/", ">", $text );
echo $output;
```

Which gives following output like you expect,

```
bla;bla<ul><li>line one</li><li>line one</li><ul>bla
line two
line tree
```

**[Live Demo](https://regex101.com/r/C823Ht/2)**

Comment: Thank you so much, appreciate that, but it does not work for me.

Comment: @Sun: One reason why it didn't work for you may be because your file might be having windows newlines which is `\r\n`. Hence the better regex to cover windows newline should be `\n|\r\n`. Your regex '(?<=>)\s+(?=)' may work fine for your case but it will also match one or more white space preceded by `>` in middle of line instead of at end of line and will stripped off that white space. Also look behind is not supported by many languages and tools, hence a safer regex to use would be `>(?:\n|\r\n)` and replace it by `>`. Updating my answer for people with languages not supporting lookbehinds.